# Referencing Same Instance of Object in Multiple Classes

Tags: c#, class, object

Can you reference (without passing the object) an object created in your main from another class if given the same name and in the same namespace in C#?

Like say you have Main, Class A and Class B. In Main you have "A ap = new A();"
If you create "A ap = new A();" inside of Class B, would both of those object reference the same instance of the object A?  So that if you changed a value in object "ap" on your main, it would also change that same variable for object "ap" in class B. Basically do they point to the same instance of Class A in the Heap?

Comment: I was unsure if they would point to the same object because they reference the same object using the same name. I didn't think so, but I am doing a class assignment and we have to draw a memory image of a program and I can not figure out how a certain variable was being effected and that seemed like the only explanation.

Comment: The names are actually different. Ap in main is different from B.ap or B.SomeMethod.Ap

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every time you use `new`, you are creating a new object on the heap, as the name implies. 
Now if you want the two classes to point to the same object, you could pass the object `ap` (or more specifically, the value of the reference variable `ap`) into class B and they would point to the same object.

Comment: That's what I thought. Just wanted to confirm.